# Query Count for each year based on single date

Tags: mysql

I am being asked to provide some reporting on Starter/Leavers based on information we are already collecting.

I am trying to figure out whether this can be done by the MySQL itself, or if I will need to make multiple calls.

At the simplest level our data structure is:

```
ID    psName     dtStart     dtLeave
```

(This is produced from multiple tables that pull in Office, Status, etc, which we might use for more complicated queries)

For a given date I can use the following Query to get the number of people in the company:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
(
  SELECT ID, psName, dtStart, dtLeave
  FROM people
) st
WHERE (dtStart <= "2016-06-04" ) 
AND (dtLeave >= "2016-06-04" OR dtLeave IS NULL)
```

I would like to be able to feed in a date, for example "2016-04-06" and get a list list of counts (either as columns or rows) for that date historically i.e.

```
6/4/2016 200
6/4/2015 175
6/4/2014 150
6/4/2014 125
6/4/2013 100
```

Does this make sense, and if so, is it possible?

Comment: do you mean group by year?

Comment: Yes - I would like the number of people employed on, say, "6th April" each year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that there is no start and end date, this query will scan all table records.

In fact, you can reduce your query to:

```
SELECT YEAR(dtStart) as 'year', COUNT(*) FROM
FROM people
WHERE MONTH(dStart) = 4 AND DAY(dStart) = 6
GROUP BY YEAR(dtStart);
```

**UPDATE**

To get people employed on the selected period:

```
SET @SelectedDate = '2016-04-06';

SELECT YEAR(dStart), COUNT(*), @SelectedDate FROM
(
  SELECT ID, psName, dtStart, dtLeave
  FROM people
  WHERE DATE_FORMAT(dtStart, '%m%d') <= DATE_FORMAT(@SelectedDate, '%m%d')
        AND DATE_FORMAT(dtleave, '%m%d') >= DATE_FORMAT(@SelectedDate, '%m%d')
) st
GROUP BY YEAR(dStart);
```

Comment: That's a lot better that I've managed to come up with but only returns counts of people who started *ON* the 6th April for each Year. Not Anyone who started on or before that date, and left after it, which is what the original gives

Comment: Well you said: `"6th April" each year`, but let me edit

Comment: Sorry - meant anyone that has started before that date each year and has not left. "In employment" rather than "recruited on"

Comment: That's just breaking down the original data set by year in which people who are here now (on the 6/4/2016) are, What I'm grasping out is for each row to be the result if the year were changed. So Row 1 would be the count if the input was "6/4/2016", Row 2 the count for "6/4/2015", etc

Comment: Ok, try it now.

Comment: Thanks for the help. That's still restricting to the current Year. Somehow we need to alter the Year for each row...

Comment: There is no year restriction, do you need it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134390/discussion-between-dan-kelly-and-mcnets).