# Translating a while loop to a promise

Tags: node.js, promise, hapi.js

I am trying to create a report which is stretching the limits of my understanding of both Node and MySQL.

I have [already established](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41937540/query-count-for-each-year-based-on-single-date) that the annual date information I need will need to be called for each year I want to display. I now have a query that can return the correct data that I need, I just need to repeat that within a Node environment.

Coming from a Delphi background the following code would provide me with the data I need

```
LoadTurnover = function (req, reply) {

    const queryDay = "-04-06";
    const maxDate  = new Date();
    let queryYear  = 2000;

    let qd        = new Date(queryYear + queryDay);
    let dateArray = [];

    while (qd < maxDate) {     
        // Get the data from the server
        let data = getData(sql);
        // 
        let turnoverObj = {};
        turnoverObj.date = qd;
        turnoverObj.Employees = data[0][0].Employees;
        turnoverObj.Leavers = data[1][0].Leavers;
        // Add current year data to our result set
        dateArray.push(turnoverObj);
        // Setup the next year condition
        queryYear ++;
        qd = new Date(queryYear + queryDay);
    }
};
```

I need to be able send a Promise to the DB server (getData) and populate the `turnoverObj` and `dateArray` appropriatly. This needs to repeat until `qd` is greater than today's date.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.map()` function of [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) promise:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird);

let dates = [];
let dateArray = [];

while (qd < maxDate) {
    dates.push(qd);
    queryYear++;
    qd = new Date(queryYear + queryDay);
}

Promise.map(dates, function(singleDate){
    return getData(sql).then(function(data){
        let turnoverObj = {};
        turnoverObj.date = singleDate;
        turnoverObj.Employees = data[0][0].Employees;
        turnoverObj.Leavers = data[1][0].Leavers;

        dateArray.push(turnoverObj);
        return;
    });
}).then(function(finalResult){
    console.log(dateArray);
});
```

Hope this helps somehow.

Comment: Unfortunately we're currently using ES6 Promises, but this might work if not no other choices. Another tack I have thought of is to use Promise.All after settting up each Query as Promise in an Array. Any reasons why not to ?

Comment: Yes, sure, it was my second thought. In such a case, you would simply do `dates.forEach` loop, in which you could create a promise using single `date` and push it to promises array. Then simply do `Promise.all(promises)`